# Can't load PHP module even though it is installed

Tags: apache-2.4

I just upgraded Ubuntu, and now apache2 won't start.

> **sudo systemctl status apache2.service**

```
apachectl[2174]: apache2: Syntax error on line 144 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load: 
Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so intoserver: 
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It seems there is an error when trying to load the php7.0 module, but php7.0 is installed.

> **php -v**

```
PHP 7.2.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (cli) (built: Jul  4 2018 16:55:24) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend 
Technologies
```

> **apache2 -v**

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2018-06-07T21:10:10
```

What do I need to do?

When I upgraded Ubuntu it said there were many modules which are now obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this solved it:

> sudo a2dismod php7.0
>
> sudo a2enmod php7.2
>
> sudo systemctl restart apache2

I guess it was trying to use the wrong PHP version